# How to use Angular js ngOptions with custom attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to populate a dropdown list with a few custom values using Angular.js `ngOptions`

Eg:-

```
<option value="' + info[x].CountryCode 
                 + '"   data-image="images/msdropdown/icons/blank.gif" 
        data-imagecss="flag ' + info[x].CountryCode 
                              + '" data-title="'
                              + info[x].CurrencyName + '" >' 
                              + info[x].CurrencyCode + '
</option>
```

Following is the data in JSON format :

```
[{
    "Id": 3,
    "CountryName": "Australia",
    "CountryCode": "au",
    "CurrencyCode": "AUD",
    "CurrencyName": "Australian Dollar",
    "CurrencyValue": 0.018,
    "PayPalCountryCode": 12,
    "PayPalCurrencyCode": 78,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "Id": 19,
    "CountryName": "Taiwan",
    "CountryCode": "tw",
    "CurrencyCode": "TWD",
    "CurrencyName": "New Taiwan Dollar",
    "CurrencyValue": 0.48,
    "PayPalCountryCode": 208,
    "PayPalCurrencyCode": 148,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "CountryName": "United States",
    "CountryCode": "us",
    "CurrencyCode": "USD",
    "CurrencyName": "US Dollar",
    "CurrencyValue": 0.016,
    "PayPalCountryCode": 225,
    "PayPalCurrencyCode": 125,
    "IsActive": true
  }]
```

I am new to Angular, could someone show me how to do this using [ngOptions](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/directive/select) ?

Comment: This is different one. This is based on custom attributes. But your suggested one is not support custom attributes. there is a huze difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Angular ng-options documentations there are no custom attributes support. so use ng-repeat directive to achieve your select box

```
<select ng-model="countrySelected" ng-change="countryChange()">
  <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.CountryCode}}" 
          data-image="images/msdropdown/icons/blank.gif" 
          data-imagecss="flag  {{country.CountryCode}}" 
          data-title="{{country.CurrencyName}}">{{country.CurrencyCode}}</option>
</select>
```

you get the selected value through ng-model. countrySelected stores your selected value.

in your controller

```
$scope.countryChange = function(){

// write your related code
}
```

Comment: But i also want an onchange event on the select...Is that possible? What i mean is a function has to be called on changing the options.

Comment: use ng-change to call function on option change

Comment: The disadvantage of your approach is that if the option is supposed to represent a null value then the model is updated with an empty string instead of null value when the use selects that option.