# Modifying ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have json object as:-

```
{    "callingCodes": [
        {
            "name": "United States",
            "code": "+1",
            "isoCode": "US",
            "isFree":"true",
            "flag":"flag us" 
        },
        {
            "name": "Turkey",
            "code": "+90",
            "isoCode": "TR",
            "isFree":"true",
        "flag":"flag tr" 
        }]
```

I am using country codes sprite image to display country flags.
 I am using ng-repeat to display the particular flag.

```
<td><span style="display: inline-block; margin-left: auto;" ng-class="{{'countryData.flag'}}"></span></td>
```

It is working fine . Now i want to use the same css classes to include the flag in the ng-options (drop-down).

```
<select id="countryCode" class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model='sendMsgData.toCountryCode' 
       ng-options="supportedCode.code as (supportedCode.code + '(' + supportedCode.isoCode + ')') for supportedCode in supportedCountryCallingCodes">
                 <option value="">Country Code</option>
              </select>
```

How can i achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264051/how-to-use-ng-class-in-select-with-ng-options

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323179/how-to-use-angular-js-ngoptions-with-custom-attributes

Comment: @SachinKariyattin I tried that. But no luck.

Comment: @hadiJZ Here i am using css class to display the flag image.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-repeat` on `option` tag:

```
<select id="countryCode" class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="sendMsgData.toCountryCode">
    <option ng-repeat="supportedCode in supportedCountryCallingCodes" value="supportedCode.code" ng-class="countryData.flag">{{supportedCode.code}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

add options-class

```
  <select id="countryCode" class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model='sendMsgData.toCountryCode'   options-class="countryData.flag"
   ng-options="supportedCode.code as (supportedCode.code + '(' + supportedCode.isoCode + ')') for supportedCode in supportedCountryCallingCodes">
             <option value="">Country Code</option>
          </select>
```